# string concatenation with constants

Tags: php, constants, php-5.4

I have only PHP 5.4 available at my current hoster and I always get errors with class constants in my code. Apparently, it's not allowed to define array constants. I changed the constant to a static variable to make it work. Now I get this syntax error:

```
    syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'
```

I try to define strings that consist of concatenated constants.

```
public static $arr = [KEY_ONE => "string " . MyClass::CONSTANT . " string"]
```

is this possible or do all constants have to be static variables now?

Comment: Maybe a question of operator preference, did you try putting parentheses around the concatenation? Like in `[KEY_ONE => ("string " . MyClass::CONSTANT . " string")]`.

Answer (score 3):

In the variable declaration you cannot do operations. Neither concatenation nor math operations.

You can do it in construct method;

```
public static $arr = [];

public function __construct(){
  self::$arr = [KEY_ONE => "string " . MyClass::CONSTANT . " string"];
}
```

Comment: Or some sort of an `init()` method if you don't want to instantiate an object.

Comment: This limitation of PHP 5.4 is informed here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php (see Example #1 property declarations). The possibility of doing concatenations, in class member variables, was introduced as of PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

if you are making array try like this:

```
public static $arr = array("KEY_ONE" => "string " . MyClass::CONSTANT . " string");
```