# Use private var in declaration of other private var in php

Tags: php, php-7

Is there a way to use a private variable to declare an other private variable? My Code looks like this:

```
class MyClass{
    private $myVar = "someText";
    private $myOtherVar = "something" . $this->myVar . "else";
}
```

But this ends in a `PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Tried it with and withoud `$this->`

Is there a way to do this in php?

Comment: Answer, no.  Do it in the constructor.  Same with all class vars private or not.

Comment: **NOT** possible. You cannot initialize class variables with any expression that isn't resolvable at compile-time, and even that compile-time expression support is only available in newer PHP versions. earlier versions could not use expressions, period.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988721/string-concatenation-with-constants/37988890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values for properties can't be based on other properties at compile-time. However, there are two alternatives.

### Constant expressions

Constants can be used in default values:

```
class MyClass {
    const MY_CONST = "someText";
    private $myVar = self::MY_CONST;
    private $myOtherVar = "something" . self::MY_CONST . "else";
}
```

As of PHP 7.1, such a constant could itself be private (`private const`).

### Initialising in the constructor

Properties can be declared with no default value, and assigned a value in the class's constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    private $myVar = "someText";
    private $myOtherVar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myOtherVar = "something" . $this->myVar . "else";
    }
}
```